# Multiple MQTT connections using PAHO failing

Tags: java, mqtt, messagebroker

Am trying to maintain two MQTT connections using PAHO library.If i maintain the same object Subscription hangs on second subscription, but if i create a new client it works but closes the first subscription. Below is my code snippet. What could i be missing?.

```
try {
        logging.info(logPreString + "| "
                + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " | "
                + "Subscribing to topic: ");

        // Construct the connection options object that contains connection parameters  
        connectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        connectOptions.setCleanSession(true);
        connectOptions.setKeepAliveInterval(1000);

        // Construct an MQTT blocking mode client
        client = new MqttClient(broker, clientID, persistence);
        // Set this wrapper as the callback handler
        client.setCallback(this);

        // Connect to the MQTT server
        logging.info(logPreString + "Connecting to broker ..." + broker);
        client.connect(connectOptions);
        logging.info(logPreString + "Connected and sucscribed ");

        // Subscribe to a topic
        System.out.println("Subscribe to topic(s):  " + "| "
                + Thread.currentThread() + " | "
                + Arrays.toString(topic) + " With QOS of:" + props.getQoS());
        client.subscribe(topic, QOS);

    } catch (MqttException me) {
        logging.error(logPreString + "MqttException caught "
                + "while connecting to broker. Error: "
                + me.getMessage());
    }

}

public void subscribeAll(String[] topic, int[] QOS) {

    try {

        logging.info(logPreString + "subscribing to all ..." + broker);
        // Subscribe to a topic
        System.out.println("Subscribing to topic(s):  " + "| "
                + Thread.currentThread() + " | "
                + Arrays.toString(topic)
                + " With QOS of:" + props.getQoS());
        client.subscribe(topic, QOS);


    } catch (MqttException me) {
        logging.error(logPreString + "MqttException caught "
                + "while connecting to broker. Error: "
                + me.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

Comment: A not uncommon reason for the 'create new client' behaviour you describe is that the second connection uses the same connection ID (clientID in your code) as an existing connection, and this always (by design) results in the broker immediately/automatically disconnecting the previous connection.

Comment: Thanks [barny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2318649/barny) . It worked like charm.